# Analogy to four-index Levi-Civita symbol, $\varepsilon_{ijkl}$, but with unbound indices

Tags: matrices, summation, tensors, summation-method

Is there a symbol $\varepsilon_{ijkl}$ which is zero if any of the four indices are equal and nonzero if the indices are pairwise disjoint?

The indices $i,j,k,l$ should be of the interval $[1,N]$ where $N$ is a large positive integer (in general larger than 4).

Moreover, is it possible to decompose such an object into a sum of objects which only have two indices $\delta_{ij}$ as it is possible for the Levi-Civita symbol?

My goal is to calculate the sum
$$
\underset{\text{disjoint}}{\sum_{ijkl}}   f_1(i) f_2(j) f_3(k) f_4(l)
$$ 
which I then could write as
$$
\sum_{ijkl}  \varepsilon_{ijkl}     f_1(i) f_2(j) f_3(k) f_4(l)
$$ 
and then hopefully decompose it further with some two-index objetcs $\delta_{ij}$...

Comment: Six delta functions (one for each combination) might do the job. Or you could simply *define* a new quantity. I can expand to an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @TheCount  Are you thinking of something like $\prod^N_{i} \prod_{j<i} (1-\delta_{ij})$?

Comment: @KitterCatter yes, exactly.

Comment: Yes an answer would be nice. Thank you.